# Why would the signature be ... -> Result<char*string>?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm following Scott's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDalzi7mhdY), and one of the examples he brings is:

```
type Result<'a> = 
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of string
let pchar (charToMatch, input) =
    if System.String.IsNullOrEmpty (input) then
        Failure "no input!"
    else
        let first =  input.[0]
        if  first = charToMatch then
            let remaining = input.[1..]
            Success (charToMatch, remaining)
        else
            let msg = sprintf "exepecting '%c' got '%c'" charToMatch first
            Failure msg
```

Visual Studio Code is showing that the signature of the `pchar` function is:

`char*string->Result<char*string>` :

[vscode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peN53.png)

**Should the return type be just `Result<'a>`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that you can use a `Result` type to wrap the outcome of any operation such that you can model the control flow with your business logic.  This is especially useful in scenarios where there is overlap between "business errors" and "exceptions".  In your example, a string is being parsed one character at a time, and the function is returning the parsed character along with the rest of the string (as an F# Tuple).

`Result` is a generic type, so it can represent the the result of any operation.  The value of the `'a` type-parameter for the `Result` type will be identical to the return type of the function if it did not return a `Result`.  Consider a simple example like the following:

`let f () = ('t', "est")`

The compiler tells us this has the type signature `unit -> char * string`.  That's because the function always takes a `unit` (empty/void) parameter and returns a tuple of a single character and a string.  If we change that function slightly to return a `Result`, like this:

`let f () = ('t', "est") |> Success`

Now the compiler tells us the signature is `unit -> Result<char * string>`.  The same as the original return type of the function, wrapped in the `Result` type.  Your example is just the same, except that the character and string tuple returned are based on the input parameters, and the function can return a failure if the input parameter is null or an empty string.

You could easily work with your `Result` types if you define a `bind` function that "unwraps" the result and passes the value inside it to another function, `f`:

```
let bind f = function
| Success s -> f s
| Failure f -> Failure f
```

Using `bind`, you could then easily pass the result of your `pchar` call to another function that uses the value, without that function having to explicitly take a `Result` type:

```
let printChar (c, str) =
    printfn "Matched Char %A, Remaining String: '%s'" c str

pchar ('a', "aaab") |> bind (printChar >> Success)
```

I often use this pattern, but I add a second generic parameter to the `Result` type that represents the `events` or `effects` of the function.  This increases the utility of the `Result` type by allowing us to have specific `Failure` events that we can handle in code (rather than checking for  specific strings), or by including domain events (such as warnings) or side-effects along with our successful results.

I use a type called `OperationResult` for this, to avoid confusion with the built-in F# `Result` type.  Since I sometimes include events/effects successful results as well as failures, I define a type for `SuccessfulResult` that is either just the return value, or the return value along with a list of events.  All together, that gives the following types to define an `OperationResult`:

```
/// Represents the successful result of an Operation that also yields events
/// such as warnings, informational messages, or other domain events
[<Struct>]
type SuccessfulResultWithEvents<'result,'event> =
    {
        Value: 'result
        Events: 'event list
    }

/// Represents the successful result of an Operation,
/// which can be either a value or a value with a list of events
[<Struct>]
type SuccessfulResult<'result,'event> =
    | Value of ResultValue: 'result
    | WithEvents of ResultWithEvents: SuccessfulResultWithEvents<'result,'event>
    member this.Result =
        match this with
        | Value value -> value
        | WithEvents withEvents -> withEvents.Value
    member this.Events =
        match this with
        | Value _ -> []
        | WithEvents withEvents -> withEvents.Events    


/// Represents the result of a completed operation,
/// which can be either a Success or a Failure
[<Struct>]
type OperationResult<'result,'event> =
    | Success of Result: SuccessfulResult<'result,'event>
    | Failure of ErrorList: 'event list
```

I have all this packaged up in a library on [GitHub](https://github.com/CurryOnCoders/CurryOn/tree/master/CurryOn.FSharp.Control) (and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CurryOn.FSharp.Control/)) along with a Computation Expression called `operation` if you want to use it.  The GitHub page has some examples as well.

Comment: thanks so much. my mind is about to explode pondering this `let f () = ('t', "est") |> Success` - i'm not understanding how it is possible for it to know implicitly how to convert a *tuple* to a *Result<'a>* type??

Comment: @AlexGordon It doesn't convert the tuple.  Think of `Success` as a generic constructor that takes any type, `'a`, and returns a `Result<'a>`.  In this case, the `'a` type is the `char * string` tuple, but it could equally be a `Guid option` or a `System.Net.IPAddress`.  It just knows that whatever type the thing is that you pass it, it will construct a `Result` of that type where the data for the `Success` case is the thing it was passed.

Comment: got it! great explanation thank you. how about this one? `let bind f = function
| Success s -> f s
| Failure f -> Failure f` ? we pass some parameter `f` to *bind* and what happens? how does it know whether to go to the *Success* or *Failure* branch? how does it match to those two?

Comment: one more question on  `unit -> Result<char * string>` -- is the reason that the return value is `Result<char * string>` because this value would be the *superset* of `Success<'a> `*union* `Failure <string>`?

Answer (score 5):

`Result<'a>` is a *generic* type which has `'a` as a type parameter. When you write `Success (charToMatch, remaining)` compiler infers this generic type parameter as a tuple of `char` and `string` : `Result<char*string>`. You can write `Success ()` and you'll get a `Result<unit>` type.

Also in F# when you list arguments for your function in parentheses with commas like you did `(charToMatch, input)`, it means your function's expecting a tuple, which means you can't use [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/). For currying to be available you should define function like that:
`let pchar charToMatch input = ...`

Answer (score 1):

@kagetoki is correct that F# infers the type from the usage.

Also, this look like a parser combinator library. The purpose of `pchar` is to attempt to extract a character from the input. If successful return the character and the rest of the string, a natural way to represent that is `char*string`. This is wrapped in a `Result` to support failures therefore the final return type should be: `Result<char*string>`.

Comment: but the failure is NOT char*string, it is just string

Comment: @AlexGordon That's correct, but the `Failure` type is not generic here.  In your `Result` type, only the success case is generic, `Failure` is always string, so it does not influence the generic type signature.